# AWS Amplify with Typescript and Typescript Lambdas

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, serverless

I'm using a nextjs frontend with typescript and for the backend I'm using AWS Amplify. I want to write my Lambda functions in Typescript. But if i do, i have one tsconfig.json in the root of my project (for nextjs) and one tsconfig.json in my lambda function. Actually it works, but the problem is that typescript is looking for node_modules in the root of my project, so i have to install the depencies in my nextjs frontend and i want to avoid it.

My file structure look like this:

```
appchen
 ┣amplify
 ┃ ┗ backend
 ┃   ┗ function
 ┃     ┗ appchenAuthPostConfirmation
 ┃       ┣ src
 ┃       ┃ ┣ node_modules 
 ┃       ┃ ┣ index.ts
 ┃       ┃ ┗ package.json     
 ┃       ┣ appchenAuthPostConfirmation-cloudformation-template.json       
 ┃       ┗ tsconfig.json
 ┣ public
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ app
 ┃ ┃ ┣ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┗ aws-exports.js
 ┣ package.json
 ┗ tsconfig.json
```

My root tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules, amplify"]
}
```

And the tsconfig in my function looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "src": ["./src"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["src/node_modules", "src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I also so tried the default setup with a lib directory like mentioned in the offical docs (https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/build-options/), but the problem stays the same. How can i force typescript to use the node_modules in functions src directory instead of the one in my root directory? Is it even possible with nested tsconfig files?

Answer (score 0):

If a dependency is not imported by the Next.js application, it will **not** be included in the final web app bundle.

This means that even though you have to install the dependencies in the root directory for TypeScript to recognize them, these dependencies won't bloat your web app's bundle size or affect its performance. They are simply there for development and compilation purposes.

Therefore, continuing with your current setup should be fine. It leverages TypeScript's capabilities while keeping your frontend and backend concerns appropriately separated. As long as you're vigilant about not importing backend-only dependencies into your Next.js app, you won't face issues with unnecessary dependencies in your web app bundle.